# Lisp Biased Number Generator

Tags: random, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Is there a way to specify bias in a random generator in lisp?

For instance if I had a range of numbers. How can I specify that the numbers in the first half of the range are 3× more likely than those in the last half?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29360071/1281433), and it handles arbitrary weights very well.  However, it does require two calls to **random**, and that might be undesirable.  Another approach would be to create a vector with elements that occur according to their intended frequency.  E.g., if you have elements a and b that should be chosen with probability 1/3 and 2/3, then you can create an array **(a b b)** and select randomly from that.

```
(defun biased-generator (values weights)
  (multiple-value-bind (total values)
      (loop for v in values
         for w in weights
         nconc (make-list w :initial-element v) into vs
         sum w into total
         finally (return (values total (coerce vs 'vector))))
    (lambda ()
      (aref values (random total)))))
```

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *gen* (biased-generator '(a b) '(1 2)))
*GEN*
CL-USER> (loop for i from 1 to 100 collect (funcall *gen*))
(A A B A B A A B B A B B A A A B A A B A A A B A A A B B B B B A B B B B A A B
 A B B A A A A B B B A A A A B A A B B B A A B B B A B B B B B B B B B B A B A
 A A A B B B B A B A A B B A B A A B B B B B)
CL-USER> (let ((abs (loop for i from 1 to 10000 collect (funcall *gen*))))
           (list (count 'a abs)
                 (count 'b abs)))
(3293 6707)
```

Comment: You can save space by RLE-compressing your array into `(weight. value)` pairs.  Then to select you loop over that list, subtracting the weight from the randomly-selected number until it is <= 0, at which point you've found the element to select.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard For big datasets that'd definitely be an option, though there's of course a tradeoff that instead of a single constant time access, you're doing a bunch of arithmetic.  It'd be an interesting case for some profiling.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Even if you make an assoc of accumulating weights so the result of the body would be something like `(cdr (assoc (random total) assoc :test #'<))` Joshuas constant time lookup will always be faster at the cost of some extra memory consumed. memory is cheap :-)

Comment: @Sylwester, that's a good idea, and using accumulated weights you could also store them in an array and do a binary search.  Even if we assume running out of memory isn't a problem, looking into a huge array is going to be bad for the cache.  I'm not sure under what conditions the strategies tie.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in 2 steps:

First, select a random number in some arbitrary range, and determine if it's in the first 3/4 of the range. If it is, select a random number in the first half of the given range, otherwise select a random number in the second half:

```
(defun biased_random(low high) {
    (let ((temp (random 1.0))
          (middle (floor (+ high low) 2)))
      (if (< temp 0.75)
          (+ low (random (- middle low)))
          (+ middle (random (- high middle)))))
```